# Redis Simple Production Server Specification

Tags: server, redis, specifications, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, redislabs

Currently I use redislabs to host my redis server, but redislabs cloud server not available in my web server hosting (softlayer) so the performance of my web server is decrease because of network latency (~20ms for 1 trip)

Because of that reason, I want to create a VPS to host redis in softlayer so my web server can connect to the redis server through LAN.

From redislabs i know that it consume ~400MB memory and has ~250 ops/sec in normal day, but can go to ~1500 ops/sec when we have an event like flash sale.

The question is which server specification can handle that kind of traffic?

Is VPS using 1 CPU x 4GB memory is enough?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the softlayer portal control when ordering a VPS there are many options with the characteristics that you want, we can not give you the specific characteristics for your requirements because we do not know if it will fulfill your expectations.

I could suggest you to order a hourly VPS with the characteristics you want and you can try it, if it does not work you can cancel it immediately to do not incur huge costs as with a monthly server.